# Ratios of $HM:GM=12:13$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, means

> If the ratio of $HM$ between two positive numbers $a$ and $b$ ($a>b$) is to their $GM$ as $12$ to $13$, find $a:b$

My attempts:

$\dfrac{HM}{GM}=\dfrac{12}{13}\implies \dfrac{\dfrac{2ab}{a+b}}{\sqrt{ab}}=\dfrac{12}{13}\implies 13\sqrt{ab}=6(a+b)$

$\dfrac{13}{6}=\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a}}$

Now, $6=2\cdot 3$ only (if not concern with $1$)

Hence I tried to break $\dfrac{13}{6}=\dfrac{c_1}{2}+\dfrac{c_2}{3}$

A bit more trial and error gives $c_1=3$ and $c_2=2$.

Hence ratio is $9:4$

But I want to know the method in which trials and errors are not incorporated, please help.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt{\dfrac ab}=p\implies p+\dfrac1p=\dfrac{13}6\iff0=6p^2-13p+6=(3p-2)(2p-3)$

If $p=\dfrac23,\dfrac ab=\dfrac49,\dfrac a4=\dfrac b9=k$(say)

$a=4k,b=?$

Comment: 9k...........+1

Comment: The goal is to find $a:b$ , so you can pretty well stop at $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{4}{9}$. :)